First attempt with Lists and lookups failing
I have a list, "TrainingWaves" that has a series of dates for stages of training (eg basic, intermediary, advanced). So each row is a different set of dates for training sessions
I have a second list "UserRecord" which has Username, Grade, TrainingWave lookup, Basic (lookup), BasicComplete (yes/no), Intermediary (lookup), IntermediaryComplete (yes/no).
I've entered the user, their grade, selected which wave and its then correctly auto populating the date lookups from the other list.
What I want to do is have a view where the Complete fields are hidden but the Basic, Intermediary etc is colour coded... if complete then green, if not complete and future dated no formatting, if not complete and overdue its red. The problem is that whatever code I put into the JSON the content disappears.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@BasicComplete, 'ms-bgColor-green', if(@currentField.lookupValue < @now'','ms-bgColor-red', '')"
  }
}

